# codeigniter database error number 1052

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, where-clause

here is the exact error:

```
Error Number: 1052

Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

SELECT * FROM (`membership_personal`) JOIN `membership_account` ON `membership_account`.`memberid` = `membership_personal`.`id` JOIN `swapaccount` ON `swapaccount`.`memberid` = `membership_account`.`memberid` WHERE `id` = '5'

Filename: /home/phpgod/public_html/johnnyarias/ci_website/models/generalfeaturesmodel.php

Line Number: 57
```

I know that it has to do with the id field being present in multiple tables of the join.  So my question is how do make sure that the id field in the where clause is applied only to the id field in the member_personal table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE `member_personal `.`id` = '5'
```

Comment: it saying: Unknown column 'member_personal.id=5' in 'where clause'

Comment: how exactly would u put the above where clause in codeigniter's database methods?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an error is because the field `id` is present in multiple tables. So it is impossible for MySql to decide which table's `id` are you referring to.

The solution is to specify the tablename as well as the column name. Ex:

```
`tablename`.`id` = '5'
```

Comment: right, but how would you put that using codeigniters database class?

Comment: i put it this way:  $this->db->where("`member_personal.id = '$memberid'");

Comment: do you know how to properly do it using codeigniters database class?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('member_personal.id',5);
```